# Can we use collection types(List, Set, Map) as cluster key in Cassandra?

Tags: list, dictionary, cassandra, set

Is this valid in Cassandra? Can we use Set, List, Map as cluster key.

1)

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
  id text,
  exams SET<text>,
  courses list<text>,
  results map<text, text>

  PRIMARY KEY (id, exams)
);
```

2. CREATE TABLE employee (
   id text,
   exams SET,
   courses list,
   results map<text, text>

   ```
   PRIMARY KEY (id, courses)
   ```

   );
3. CREATE TABLE employee (
   id text,
   exams SET,
   courses list,
   results map<text, text>

   ```
   PRIMARY KEY (id, results)
   ```

   );

Answer (score 2):

You can use collections as part of the primary key but they have to be [`frozen` collections](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.x/cql/cql_reference/collection_type_r.html).

This schema is invalid:

```
CREATE TABLE student_results (
    studentid text,
    results list<text>,
    PRIMARY KEY (studentid, results)
)
```

If you try to create the table, it will throw an invalid query exception:

```
Invalid non-frozen collection type for PRIMARY KEY component
```

The correct schema is when the collection is frozen:

```
CREATE TABLE student_results (
    studentid text,
    results frozen<list<text>>,
    PRIMARY KEY (studentid, results)
)
```

Cheers!